# Error with Spring WebSocket

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am developing a WebSocket Application using Spring boot.

***WebSocketConfig.java***

```
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(getHandler(), "/marco");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler getHandler() {
        return new WebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

***WebSocketHandler.java***

```
public class WebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello"));
    }
}
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ge.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringWebSocket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringWebSocket</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***WebSocket.html***

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>I am in Main Page!!</h1>
</body>
    <head>
            <script>
                    var url='ws://localhost:8080'+'/SpringWebSocket/marco';
                    var sock=new WebSocket(url);
                    sock.onopen=function(){
                        console.log("Socket was Opened!");
                    }
                    sock.onmessage=function(e){
                        console.log("Received Message "+e.data);
                    }
                    sock.onclose=function(){
                        console.log("Connection was closed!");
                    }
                    function hello(){
                        console.log("Hello Iftekhar!!");
                        sock.send("Marco!");
                    }
                            </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The Server code is running on tomcat with port-8080 and client is running on tomcat9 with port - 8090. But when i am doing http://localhost:8090/WebSocket.html . I am getting the below error on console.

```
WebSocket.html:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/SpringWebSocket/marco' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

The Server side Code can be found here - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/SpringWebSocket

Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot, by default, serves content on the root context path (“/”).

So you should try

```
ws://localhost:8080/marco
```

instead of

```
ws://localhost:8080/SpringWebSocket/marco
```